# Tomcat deploy via maven URL

Tags: maven, url, tomcat, deployment, war

I have a .war file in an Maven url (like : http://maven.x.ch/maven2-x/x/x/x/x/x-x/01.03.00.00/myFile.war)

How can I directly deploy it in tomcat ?

Comment: cd [tomcat]/webapps; wget http://maven.x.ch/maven2-x/x/x/x/x/x-x/01.03.00.00/myFile.war

Comment: Thats the way to do it from a shell. If "Maven url" is a Maven repository, you should go for a [continous integration system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), like Bamboo or [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/).